# Get GitHub project version

Tags: java, github

I'm making a library and I continously release updates on its GitHub page.
Because of that I want to find a way to get the latest version number on GitHub to alert the user if there is any update.
Is there a better way than getting the HTML content of the web page and checking that?
I'd prefer not to use an external library.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [GiitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), specifically, the [Releases endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/), assuming that you are in fact using releases to track your versions.

EG:

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest`
Will return information about the latest release for that repository

Assuming you don't want to bother with writing your on client to use it, avoid re-inventing the wheel and use [one of github's wrappers](https://developer.github.com/libraries/), for example, [this one](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core)

Answer (score 2):

The github API provides this functionality. Did you do any research before asking?

[Link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) for convenience.